# Why is my NumberFormatException not being caught in my try-catch?

Tags: java, swing, exception, try-catch, numberformatexception

So I am trying to `catch (NumberFormatException ex)` in my code:

```
private void Processes() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // New Thread "processesThread" will start here.
    final Object mon = threadBlock;
    Thread processesThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (mon) {
                try {
                    try {
                        try {
                            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            // "runnableTogether" will be the number that the user inputs in the GUI.
                            switch (runnableTogether) {
                                case 4:
                                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/SoundRecorder.exe"));
                                case 3:
                                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/taskmgr.exe"));
                                case 2:
                                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"));
                                case 1:
                                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe"));
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                                destroyProcesses(processes);
                                break;
                                default:
                                invalidInput();
                                break;
                            }
                            mon.wait();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                        }
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    nullInput();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at tf2_account_chief.TF2_Account_Chief.actionPerformed(TF2_Account_Chief.java:425)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the [PasteBin link](http://pastebin.com/cucRR03E) for the full code!

Comment: can you post the full stack trace. the reason of the exception can be better seen in the "caused by" clause.

Comment: @erencan That is the full stack trace. I am using NetBeans if that changes anything

Comment: what is there in the TF2_Account_Chief.java:425 ?

Comment: I will post a PasteBin link of the full code.

Comment: @erencan Ok. I added the PasteBin link.

Comment: @fvu I don't understand what you mean? I never said it wasn't clear... I am just learning to use try catch, that's all. You could be a little more understanding, maybe...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the stack trace of the exception shows, the exception is not thrown by the code above, but by the `actionPerformed()` method of the class `f2_account_chief.TF2_Account_Chief`, which calls `Integer.parseInt()` somewhere.

Comment: Check the PasteBin link I added.

Comment: Why would I check it? Check my answer and read the stack trace instead. The exception is thrown at line 425, not by the above code.

Comment: This is what is at line 425: `runnableTogether = Integer.parseInt(runnableTogetherInput.getText());` But what would I do to catch that?

Comment: You would enclose the lines 425 to 434 in a try block, catch NumberFormatException, and inside the cacth block, do whatever you want if the runnableTogetherInput.getText() is not a valid Integer.

Comment: @user2506658 Write the `Integer.parseInt(runnableTogetherInput.getText())` one in a try/catch and then catch the `ParseException`.